# JQuery image slider not working... What have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

It should be simple image slider...
Why, o why doesn't this work? I followed some tutorial "to the letter", but it's video tutorial on youtube so I don't have their working code on some site to compare, but nevertheless, by their instruction and my week knowledge, I can't find mistake...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slider {
width:500px;
height:250px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:30px auto;
background-image:url(img/loading.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}
.slider img {
width:800px;
height:350px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Slider(){
$(".slider#img1").show("fade",500);
$(".slider#img1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

var sc=$(".slider img").size();
var count=2;

setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider #img"+count).show("slide",{direction:"right"}, 500);
    $(".slider #img"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    if(count==sc){
    count=1;
    } else {
    count=count+1;
}, 6500);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Slider()">

<div class="slider">
<img id="img1" src="img/1.jpg" />
<img id="img2" src="img/2.jpg" />
<img id="img3" src="img/3.jpg" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ??

Comment: No, it just won't work... W3 Validator passes "doctype and alt missing" errors witch are irrelevant.

Comment: Update: Opera Dragonfly returns "Undefined variable: Slider" when I try to load script...

Comment: you forgot to put closing bracket `}` of setInterval function after else ?

Comment: Instead of " count=count+1;
}, 6500);
}
}"
I need  count=count+1;
} }, 6500);
}

Thnx a lot mate! I lost last hour finding mistake.. Damn notpad and lack of sleep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have misplaced your `}` bracket for `else` and `setInterval`

```
function Slider(){
  $(".slider#img1").show("fade",500);
  $(".slider#img1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

  var sc=$(".slider img").size();
  var count=2;
  setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider #img"+count).show("slide",{direction:"right"}, 500);
    $(".slider #img"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    if(count==sc){
      count=1;
    } else {
      count=count+1;
    }
  }, 6500);  //<---here
}
```